# How to add data from Contact and Display it in ListBox dynamically

Tags: windows-phone-7

My requirement as follows 
1) Select the contact from the Contact ( select one or many) 
2) Add the Mobile no and Contact name from selected contact in ListBox
3) To delete : Select a contact in the ListBox and delete dynamically and refresh data

My Problems:
a) How to I bind data from contact to ListBox?

```
 PhoneCtc = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();

PhoneCtc.Completed += new EventHandler(PhoneCtc_Complete);


public void PhoneCtc_Complete(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
        {

          string No     = e.PhoneNumber;
          string Name      = e.DisplayName;

// how to add this data dynamically to listbox and display ?

 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define the **DataTemplate** of the items in the listbox as shown below:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding No}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then you'll have to create a class **Contact** containing No and Name:

```
public class Contact
    {
        public string No { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in code when you want to add an element, you just need to initialize an instance class ***Contact*** and set variables then write **listBox1.Items.Add(***Contact***);**

Comment: I am not sure. If I select 10 contacts using phoneNumberChooser, the contact class will only store one of the latest contact info. Thus,this ListBox will only contan one contact info.

Comment: No buddy, every time you launch the  PhoneNumberChooserTask(), you'll have to initialize a class of contact and insert it into the listbox and it should work fine and every time you choose a contact it will be added to the list. Try it :)