# Can ListBox have columns in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I have used a list box to display few dates. A string contains a date followed by a number. And this date is written to as an item to the listbox. I have put white spaces after the date. But it has alignment problem. Is there anyway I can set tab after the date? Or is there a way to set columns for listbox?

Mon, Sep 1, 2011 26

Thu, Oct 16, 2011(longer..) 30

I cant use a grid because, the items will be dynamically generated, so the number of rows cannot be known before hand.

Is there any control with scroll bars which can display values in the above manner? There no control called the ListView in WP7 right?. No binding is used here, so i cant use the DataTemplate!! Help!!

Alfah

Comment: asking the obvious first question - why is there no binding? and you don't need a control with scrollbars, since you can wrap most things in a scrollviewer

Comment: Bindings are a good thing. Not using bindings is not only silly, it's also stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924879/how-to-add-data-from-contact-and-display-it-in-listbox-dynamically/7925928#7925928), might be helpful because what you're asking about can be done this way.

**UPDATE:**
In that case you'll have to do it using c# code as follows:
1- Add the date to a textblock:

```
TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
t.Text = _Date_;
t.Width = 100;  // set width you want to make all date entires have the same width
```

2- Add the number to another textblock:

```
TextBlock n = new TextBlock();
n.Text = _number_;
n.Width = 50;  // set width you want to make all date entires have the same width
```

3- Add them both to a stackpanel:

```
StackPanel st = new StackPanel();
st.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
st.Children.Add(t);
st.Children.Add(n);
```

4- Add the stack to the listbox:

```
listBox1.Children.Add(st);
```

And you'll have to repeat this for every element you want to add.

Comment: That solution can be used only when we have binding. I have no binding to the list box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WrapPanel as ItemsPanel from Silverlight Toolkit, Please check the following: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-wrappanel-in-depth and http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/507167/Windowsplusphoneplus7plusHowplustoplusshowplustwop

---

1) Download [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

2) Add Referance: Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit

3) Add the following in phone:PhoneApplicationPage source code 

xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

4) Listbox control example:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="100" ItemHeight="50"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item1"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item3"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item4"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item5"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item6"/>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem. 
But I am guessing, using a stackpanel with horizontal orientation should help. 
Any luck with Expression Blend? You might find controls that can solve your problem.

Comment: These items dates will be known only when the user selects them from the calender. And i would need a scroll bar too. Think stackpanel wont do. Some contol which holds other controls or some control tht allow me to diplay in columns

Answer (score 0):

you can set the template for ListItem. If it will be a grid with two columns it solves your problem

Comment: could you give little more explanation on this? I'm looking for something which does not use binding.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Grid. And databind it. Seriously, no reason to fool around with any other solutions.